# Get read acknowledgement for Policies on SharePoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, sharepoint-addin, designer-workflow, auditing

I have policies and procedures document on a SharePoint 2013 library that I would like all users to acknowledge that he/she has read policies/procedures on a yearly basis or anytime we update the policies/procedures and record the username and time stamp of the acknowledgement to another list in SharePoint.

Ideally, I would like to capture the acknowledgement as soon as the user click on the document link.

If possible, I would like to present a dialog box to the user once they click on the document link and have the option to click a button to acknowledge the document.

any suggestion would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

We have implemented same scenario for a client. We can implement following components to complete this.

- Create policies in a list using Rich text box field or keep as your documents.
- Create a custom form to show the policy data and add a button(s) to capture acknowledgment.
- Create one more form to select the employee groups to which you want to send and policies you want to send. This will give the ability to send policies any time and any group/user.
- You can also create a timer job to send on scheduled interval.

Let me know if you are looking for the same kind solution. I will help you further if required.

Thanks,
Venkat Konjeti

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I'm working on a similar concept but I'm not getting the outcome that looking for. i have a InfoPath form that i use to collect the information but the user have to manually type the information in which is time consuming. our policies are on PDF format, we send a link on an email whenever new changes are made. so trying to get the acknowledgement once they click on the link. lets say they get a prompt to acknowledge the document once the click on the link from the email. java scrips maybe...

Comment: You can`t capture the response by clicking pdf file link. You can embed the pdf file on a web page and you can write a logic on page load to log the response. Or you can enforce a user to click on a button to log the response.

Answer (score 0):

The way I approached these kinds of requirements was with a simple custom list for ease of assignment by the compliance officer and a workflow to create an item on a task list assigned to the end-user.

The compliance officer creates a new item on the "assign policy or training" list - this consists of a multi-select people picker (for choosing which employees need to acknowledge they have read the materials) and a multi-select choice column with checkboxes for which materials need to be read and acknowledged (for each of the various policies which need active responses - different departments here get different training assignments and policies).

A workflow fires on these new item creation in the assignments list, which creates a task for each user of the type(s) matching what was checked-off as required. The workflow then sends an email to each user with the compliance text telling the user what to do (follow this link, read the text, acknowledge read).

The link takes them to the customized edit task form, which was modified to embed the relevant materials (pdf file, video training, etc.) and ends with a checkbox labeled "I have read and understood the RequiredPolicyThing".

The legal department wanted a checkbox requiring the user *actively* acknowledge having received and read the policy - just counting them as having read the policy when they just click on the link to it, with no indication that the link even necessarily worked for them (maybe they had a browser issue which blocked the pdf embed?), would not have met legal requirements.

This was fairly easy to set up - and I have a list with each user, the time it was assigned, time stamp of when they acknowledged it, and a checkbox showing they have actively acknowledged the policy. Also a simple view will tell the compliance officer who hasn't completed it, and I even threw in a past-due view (created date plus X days and not completed) for easy followup.